# Apache2 fails to start Putty AWS Windows

Tags: linux, server, window, putty

I am trying to start a django project using an AWS EC2 linux server using putty on windows, however Apache2 is showing an error related to the fact that the address is already used as shown in the next code:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-25 19:51:59 UTC; 2min 7s ago
Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
Process: 15022 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine 
the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'Serv
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: 
could not bind to address [::]:80
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: 
could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: Action 'start' failed.
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 apachectl[15022]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 25 19:51:59 ip-172-31-4-25 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I already tried to verify the status of the network using the next code, but the failure still the same.

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

I also tried to verify the service listening ports using the next code, and the output was:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-4-25:~$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      15122/httpd
```

I would appreciate any recommendation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check Skype, if its running then close first and then start Apache service.
Skype also use port 80.